# MySQL Access Denied for user ''@'localhost'

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble creating a database on my local server using MySQL.

Approach:

Start mysqld as administrator 
Start MySQL as administrator

```
mysql> create database db_name;
```

MySQL throws an error indicating, "Access Denied for user ''@'localhost to database 'db_name'.

What do I need to specify to MySQL to create a database?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Type `show grants for 'administrator'@'localhost';`  What do you see?

Comment: access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: Please review @Vhortex answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a valid user/password combination to gain access to MYSQL.
You also need that the user you are using have the privileged to create a database.

On default, new users have zero access to the database management including creation.

Comment: I recall being able to login just fine. I guess I forgot how to login

Comment: Usually the problem is with the user access. This might help but it is worth a shot, you can strictly forced a username to be able to access with only a specific hostname/ip address. NOTE: @Tim Biegeleisen beats me to is

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Perhaps if I can just burn this into my brain (or save a text file) MySQL will only work through the command prompt.